# Gremlin Order by latest Date

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I added vertices with `createDate` as a property. I want to retrieve the latest created vertex using `createDate` property.

How can I retrieve this. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just `order()` your vertices in descending order by the `createDate` and grab the first one:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.V().order().by('createDate', desc).limit(1)
==>v[2]
gremlin> g.V().order().by('createDate', desc).limit(1).values('createDate')
==>22-OCT-2019
```

Comment: just static import `Order.desc` or refer to it directly as such.

Comment: Thank you for answering.I tried in the above way.It is giving me error as                                                                              `No such property: desc for class:`                                                                              If I use **decr** instead of **desc** it is returning me all the createDate's

Comment: can you please tell me How to import `Order.desc`.

Comment: `decr` is fine but you must be using a really old version of the Gremlin Console. that `Order.decr` was deprecated a long time ago. I suggest you upgrade your console to the latest version of 3.4.3 if you can. as far as importing `Order`, there is no need to do so in the Gremlin Console, it will do so for you automatically (as it did with `decr`. I thought you were coding in a Java application which is why I thought you need to add an `import` statement to your code

Comment: Really nice solution to this problem. I was able to sort dates stored as Strings without having to resort to casting.

Comment: For anyone using Cosmos DB, you need to use `incr` and `decr`. Took me a while to figure that out.